# ordenar una cadena alfebetica en [C] ¿cómo lo podría hacer?

Tags: c

quiero llenar un vector con nombres y luego imprimirlos en orden alfabético.
tengo una lista de contactos como en un celular y luego de llenar la cadena quiero ver la lista de contactos en orden alfabético

```
char vector[alfabeto];
for(int i;i<albeto;i++){
    printf("%s",vector[i]);
}
```

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con linq, un ejemplo es la siguiente forma

var orderByResult = from s in [alfabeto]
                   orderby s
                   select s;

por si no as usado linq la "s" es un alias y "alfabeto" en esta caso es tu vector, si no vector no tiene alguna propiedad puedes hacerlo asi en caso de tener una propiedad por ejemplo "nombre", en la parte de orderby deberia ser s.nombre.

Pero igual necesitaria mas informacion para ayudarte mejor, que es C?, turbo C, C++ o C#?

Comment: Hola. **C** es un **lenguaje de programación**. No es `C#` ni `C++`, es simplemente **C**. ¿ Te has pasado por el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y/o por la [ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para ver como funciona el sitio ? Un saludo.